# Ant Concat footer task with inline text

Tags: ant

How do you include just text as a footer in an Ant concat task? This obviously doesn't work:

```
   <concat destfile=".\xxx\XXX.txt">
     <footer>
     ]]&gt;&lt;/ac:plain-text-body&gt;&lt;/ac:structured-macro&gt;
     </footer>
   </concat>
```

All the examples that I see are for including entire files. I just want to insert that much text as a footer, would like to avoid creating a separate file for it, and [Apache Ant docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) tell me that what you insert as a footer "can be text or a file". But how do you do it as text? The build error I get is "requires a file or some text", but where does the text go?

I've tried the above with quotation marks around the text, various things, but not getting anything that works.

I could do it other ways, use replaceregexp to match the end of each file, but that would be more complicated, the advantage of this is that it would add my text to the end of each file no matter what the content.

**UPDATE:**

Okay I figured this out:

```
   <concat append="true" destfile=".\xxx\XXX.txt">
    <footer>
    </footer>
  ]]&gt;&lt;/ac:plain-text-body&gt;&lt;/ac:structured-macro&gt;
  </concat>
```

The text to add as a footer goes after the footer tag, not inside it. Seems counter-intuitive, but it works.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `echo` ant task with your text added to `message` attribute and using `file` attribute on echo to redirect the message & using the file inside `concat` .

Comment: I'm pleased you figured it out.  It would be helpful for future users if you put the solution in an answer and marked it as accepted.  I know I am more likely to click on a search result if I see it has an answer.

Comment: @thekbb true, have added as answer. Will let OP to comment/accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a suggestion above, I'll post the solution I found as an answer, separate from my post. Another good suggestion above as well for a different approach.

For my part, I just needed to understand that the text for the content of the footer doesn't go inside the footer tags, that's where parameters go like `filtering="no"` and `trimleading="yes"` and so on. The input text for the footer just goes inside the concat tags, with no quotes or formatting.

Solution:

```
  <concat append="true" destfile=".\xxx\XXX.txt">
   <footer>
   </footer>
      ]]&gt;&lt;/ac:plain-text-body&gt;&lt;/ac:structured-macro&gt;
  </concat>
```

Answer (score 0):

Framed answer per my comment above:

```
<echo message="]]&gt;&lt;/ac:plain-text-body&gt;&lt;/ac:structured-macro&gt;" file=".\xxx\misc-footer.xml"/>
<concat destfile=".\xxx\XXX.txt" append="true">
     <!-- Required file to concat -->
     <fileset dir=".\xxx" file="misc-footer.xml"/>
</concat>
```

Comment: and post `concat` you can `delete` misc-footer.xml temp file created